# $(\sigma_0^{-1} SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \sigma) \cap SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is a right coset of $\Gamma_0(m)$ in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma_0(m)$ be the subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ which is defined as follows: $$\Gamma_0(m)=\left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right) \in SL(2, \mathbb{Z} : c \equiv 0 \mod{m} \right\}$$ 
Moreover, let
$$C(m) = \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{array} \right): ad=m, a>0, 0 \leq b < d, \gcd(a,b,d) = 1 \right\}$$
and $\sigma_0 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} m & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \in C(m)$.

---

I need to show that
$$\Gamma_0(m) = (\sigma_0^{-1} SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \sigma_0) \cap SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$$
and more generally we have that 
For $\sigma \in C(m)$, the set 
$$(\sigma_0^{-1} SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \sigma) \cap SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$$
is a right coset of $\Gamma_0(m)$ in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

The missing step in the theorem I am reading seems to be that I need to show (or know) that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the right cosets of $\Gamma_0(m)$ and elements of $C(m)$.